# How to access Alpine variables from normal JS?

Tags: javascript, laravel, alpine.js

I want to hide an element with Alpine after X number of seconds. So I need to run a setTimeout() that changes an x-data variable that the element's x-show is bound to.

I'm currently using the script tag with normal JS in, but I can't seem to access the x-data variables from it.

As an example:

```
<div x-data="showSomething = true">
    <script>
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.showSomething = false;
        }, 1500);
    </script>
</div>
```

I get this error whether I use "this." or not:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: showSomething is not defined**

How can I access the x-data variables from normal JS, **or is there a way to go about this in Alpine?**

**Edit:** I solved this by using x-on to listen for the event (and referring to the variables without .this within that function)

Comment: _"I get this error whether I use "this." or not:

Uncaught ReferenceError: showSomething is not defined"_ I can't reproduce it: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmzgk614/ `this` is a reference to the `window` object in that context. It's not the DOM element you expect. You could select that element with `document.querySelector('[x-data="showSomething = true"]')`

Answer (score 5):

Use `x-init`.

```xml
<div
    x-data="{ showSomething: true }"
    x-init="setTimeout(() => { this.showSomething = false; }, 1500)"
>
</div>
```